# Is it fine to assign express js application instance to global scope?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am making my own node js structure and i am using express for http server. I also saw few other structures like loopback and sails.js
They are also assigning some objects to `global`. 
So i am little bit confused about it that if i will make app global will it make any problem like security base performance base or any other issue with this way.

`Before marking it negative please mention the reason in comment so that I will not repeat this mistake again`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, having 1 or couple of variables in global context is fine. Root global objects should be very few. Anything required globally should be inside those objects.

Many libraries on client side bind to global object like moment, lodash, async (That is only way to make your object available to others,I guess)

Comment: That I know but what about really big objects like all models, connections and services of an express application like this [Example](https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8443381#file-waterline-v0-10-express-example-js-L83) what about if I will do `global.models = app.models` will it make any problem for my app ?

Comment: Sails does make all models, services available under `sails` global object (without it also using config flag). I've been using Sails for 3 years, did not face any problem due to this.

Comment: So it means that sails has this level of access `global.sails.models` ? like every model will stay in global scope ? I never used sails are you sure about it that they are putting such a big object in global ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `sails.models[<modelName>]`